# If mastered enough, could Haoshoku Haki destroy a large piece of land, maybe crack an island in half at most? (One Piece)

Tags: one-piece

I was curious because Shanks was cracking parts of Whitebeard's ship just from his presence, so couldn't that mean if mastered enough it could have more of a destructive power to physical objects instead of the mind when mastered enough?

Comment: It can go as powerful as Oda-sensei wants it to be.

Answer (score 1):

We have no way to answer that because we have not been told by oda if that is possible and we have not seen anything on that level the closest we have seen is when shanks cracked a part of whitebeard ship.

Comment: I did not want to leave you hanging so i gave you the best answer i could sorry :(.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that "Channeling a haki, able to produce the more power", I don't think so just simply releasing it 360° from your head would do any good damage! Even mastered haki user Shanks could do so far!

But yes, channeing that same energy of Conquer Haki into your sword can swinging it, probably can destroy a island to half (if you chaki is that much powerful)!

Ref: Roger vs Newgate